# How can i test the promise function at jest with react testing library?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

[image: function that i am trying to test]

I have this function and i am trying to test it here:

[image]

I am trying to make the onClose function callable, but I get an error at this line => `expect(onClose).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `onClose` function is not called directly but asyncronously after some other action, you should use the react testing library [async API](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async) [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) method which depicts that you expect something to eventually happen.

Your expectation should look like this

```
await waitFor(() => expect(onClose).toHaveBeenCalled());
```

Also don't forget to wrap your testing block with `async` in order to be able to use `await`.